# Error in installing Openstack with packstack

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack on CentOS 7.3.1611 with packstack as below.

```
$ sudo yum install -y https://www.rdoproject.org/repos/rdo-release.rpm
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install -y openstack-packstack
$ sudo packstack --allinone
```

But it doesn't work due to the error as below.

```
2017-03-18 15:35:26::INFO::shell::94::root:: [localhost] Executing script:
.......
yum update -y puppet hiera openssh-clients tar nc puppet-aodh puppet-apache puppet-barbican puppet-cassandra puppet-ceilometer puppet-ceph puppet-certmonger puppet-cinder puppet-collectd puppet-concat puppet-congress puppet-contrail puppet-corosync puppet-datacat puppet-ec2api puppet-elasticsearch puppet-firewall puppet-fluentd puppet-git puppet-glance puppet-gnocchi puppet-haproxy puppet-heat puppet-horizon puppet-inifile puppet-ipaclient puppet-ironic puppet-java puppet-kafka puppet-keystone puppet-kibana3 puppet-kmod puppet-manila puppet-memcached puppet-midonet puppet-mistral puppet-module-data puppet-keepalived puppet-mongodb puppet-mysql puppet-n1k-vsm puppet-neutron puppet-nova puppet-nssdb puppet-ntp puppet-opendaylight puppet-openstack_extras puppet-openstacklib puppet-oslo puppet-ovn puppet-pacemaker puppet-panko puppet-rabbitmq puppet-redis puppet-remote puppet-rsync puppet-sahara puppet-sensu puppet-snmp puppet-ssh puppet-staging puppet-stdlib puppet-swift puppet-sysctl puppet-systemd puppet-tacker puppet-tempest puppet-timezone puppet-tomcat puppet-tripleo puppet-trove puppet-uchiwa puppet-vcsrepo puppet-vlan puppet-vswitch puppet-xinetd puppet-zaqar puppet-zookeeper puppet >= 2.7.0
.....
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-vcsrepo
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-vlan
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-vswitch
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-xinetd
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-zaqar
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet-zookeeper
rpm -q --whatprovides puppet
rpm -q --whatprovides >=
rpm -q --whatprovides 2.7.0
.........
rpm: no arguments given for query
++ t
++ exit 1
```

This seems to be happened by the wrong yum command which is generated by packstack.
Have anyone seen same error ?